# Join tables in Laravel Eloquent method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, join, eloquent, controller

How to write this code in eloquent method ?

```
$product = DB::table('products')
             ->join('purchase', 'products.id', '=', 'purchase.id')
             ->join('sales', 'purchase.id', '=', 'sales.id')
             ->select('sales.*', 'purchase.*','products.*')
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create model Product and add one to many relationship with Purchase in Product model.

```
public function purchases()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Purchase');
}
```

Create model Purchase and add one to many relationship with Sale in Purchase model.

```
public function sales()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Sale');
}
```

Create model Sale.

You can retrieve data using following statement.

```
$products = Product::with('purchases.sales')->get();
```

Note: I am assuming the relationship as one to many you can also declare as per your data, also you can define one to many inverse relationship, please refer to laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many.

You will get purchases and sales data in different key so you can use below syntax to loop over it.

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach ($product->purchases as $purchase) {
        //Purchase data for current product
        foreach($purchase->sales as $sale){
            //Sale data for current purchase
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, its not showing data in loop,  but in dd() showing data of both models or tables, in loop fetching data from only on Product